# Session in JavaMail

Tags: java, session, authentication, jakarta-mail

In the following Code in the session object `(PasswordAuthentication )` what username and password we have to provide to send mail ? Sender's username password or receiver's credentials? 
I am really confused , I am using java Mail to send mail

```
public void sendMail(String email,String token)
    {
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
           String to = email;
          // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
          // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
          String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

          // Get the Session object.
          Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
             new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                   return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
           }
             });

          try {
           // Create a default MimeMessage object.
           Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

           // Set From: header field of the header.
           message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("Issme-Customer-Service"));

           // Set To: header field of the header.
           message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                   InternetAddress.parse(to));

          message.setSubject("Email Verification Of issme Account");

            message.setContent(
                    "<h2>Email Verification </h2>" + 
                    "<h3> Please goto  the following URL to verify your ISSME account\n </h3> " +
                     token , "text/html; charset=utf-8");


           // Send message
           Transport.send(message);

           System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

          } catch (MessagingException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
       }
```

Comment: Why would it be the receiver's credentials? It's the sender's username and password, just like you'd set in a mail client.

Comment: If this is a web application, it's probably better practice to set up a JavaMail session in the application server though. Connections to external services are a deployment environment concern and their parameters shouldn't be hardcoded.

Comment: You need to set the credentials that can authenticate to the SMTP server (sender)

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the sender's credentials which gmail's SMTP server will authenticate and then it'll send the email.

Comment: Okay If I have form details in database and wants to that details in email from code that how can I do this? 

means there is no sender which have credentials

Comment: Firstly you should not have the password directly in your database. But you can anyway query the DB and use that information to send the email.

Comment: The message has to come from "someone".  That "someone" has to have an account on a mail server.  Your program needs the credentials for that "someone" so you can login to the mail server and send the message.